# Quickfix contains tag

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol

Is there an easy way in Quickfix/J of telling whether a FIX message contains a tag which is located in a repeating group?

I would like to know if a MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh contains a bid/ask or a Ticker update without processing the message...

i.e. if I could detect the presence of  TickDirection (tag 274) I would know the snapshot is a Ticker update and deal with it appropriately.

The hacky way to do this would be to get the String and look for 274= but was hoping there was a way to do this within the API.

Thxs.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way than the 2 you have mentioned. Logically speaking there isn't any.

Comment: @DumbCoder, if you paste that as an answer I'll upvote you.  If you don't paste it, I may paste it and steal your justly deserved rep ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by DumbCoder above:

I don't think there is any other way than the 2 you have mentioned. Logically speaking there isn't any.

Comment: Invoking http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126841/should-comments-that-answer-the-question-be-flagged